# Iphone / iPad Spanish Keyboard

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, keyboard

Is there a Spanish Keyboard for iPhone iPad (with accents and ñ) or just the US one?

Thanks!

Comment: This is probably a superuser question, but the short answer is "there is a Spanish keyboard, yes."

Comment: I can´t find it in the documentation "UIKeyboardType": http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html

Comment: Are you wanting to use a specific language's (ie. Spanish) keyboard within an app running on any iPhone with any default language keyboard? Ie. You always want a given input field to have a spanish keyboard, even on a US-English/French/Italian iPhone/iPad?

Comment: YES I want to programmatically set the use of Spanish keyboard even if some users have their devices set to other languages. But I think this is not documented, maybe I´ll just put an info page saying that you need to change your keyboard to use the App.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need for a special keyboard; this is built into the standard one. A special keyboard would also be problematic, as it would significantly impede the user's ability from typing the *standard* letters, too.

All you have to do is hold down the key for the *base* character (for example, <kbd>n</kbd>). A mini-keyboard will pop up that allows you to select from all of the accented or special characters that are available for that letter. Simply tap <kbd>ñ</kbd> on that mini-keyboard.

[image: iPhone keyboard, showing special characters available for the letter E]

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings and change keyboard language. Then u ll definitely get spanish keyboard.